# Unknown character ı̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨

Tags: character-encoding, fonts

This is a bit a silly question, but I stumbled upon this strange "character" today ı̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̨̨̨̨̨̨̨̨  Try to copy it in a text editor, you will see that you have to press backspace several times in order to erase it => I suppose there are actually several caracters, but I have no idea how to analyze it further.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why so many close votes? Looks fine to me. Got an answer that could help others.

Comment: Google "unicode combining mark".  No way to help you beyond this without you describing your programming environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hex editor for viewing the raw character data. Your example includes three multibyte characters with special meanings. Here you go:

```
 ‍̸

U+0338 COMBINING LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 1.1
Unicode category: Mark, Non-Spacing

Various Useful Representations

UTF-8: 0xCC 0xB8
UTF-16: 0x0338

C octal escaped UTF-8: \314\270
XML decimal entity: &#824;

Annotations and Cross References

Alias names:
 • long slash overlay

----------------------

‍̨

U+0328 COMBINING OGONEK

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 1.1
Unicode category: Mark, Non-Spacing

Various Useful Representations

UTF-8: 0xCC 0xA8
UTF-16: 0x0328

C octal escaped UTF-8: \314\250
XML decimal entity: &#808;

Annotations and Cross References

Alias names:
 • nasal hook

Notes:
 • Americanist: nasalization
 • Polish, Lithuanian

See also:
 • U+02DB OGONEK

----------------------

ı

U+0131 LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 1.1
Unicode category: Letter, Lowercase

Various Useful Representations

UTF-8: 0xC4 0xB1
UTF-16: 0x0131

C octal escaped UTF-8: \304\261
XML decimal entity: &#305;

Annotations and Cross References

Notes:
 • Turkish, Azerbaijani
 • uppercase is U+0049 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I

See also:
 • U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I
```

I found this out using a hex editor and an program for displaying a character map. Probably you could have done it yourself. The first two are overlay characters and that’s why you have to hit backspace several times (they don’t generate a space in the text; they are modifying the previous character’s appearance).

What the characters are doing in your text nobody here can tell you. You have to find it out yourself. (Maybe random binary data in a text file?)

Comment: Nice, I haven't thought of using a hex editor. Thanks